# Cakephp model self join and how to retrieve correct array

Tags: arrays, cakephp, hash, model, self-join

I have the following model:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Sync extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Unit' => array(
            'className' => 'Sync',
            'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
        )
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Consultant' => array(
            'className' => 'Sync',
            'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
        )
    );
}
```

If I do a `$this->Sync->find('all')` I get back an array almost the way I want it:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Sync] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 22222
                    [parent_id] => 22222
                    [statistic_date] => 2012-11-14 00:00:00
                )

            [Unit] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 22222
                    [parent_id] => 22222
                    [statistic_date] => 2012-11-14 00:00:00
                )

            [Consultant] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 11111
                            [parent_id] => 22222
                            [statistic_date] => 2011-12-15 00:00:00
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 33333
                            [parent_id] => 22222
                            [statistic_date] => 2011-12-14 00:00:00
                        )
                )
      )
)
```

The problem is I want to do a condition on the consultants. Like this:

```
$this->Sync->Consultant->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Consultant.statistic_date BETWEEN ? AND ?' => 'array(
            '2011-12-01 00:00:00', '2011-12-31 00:00:00'
         )'
    )
))
```

However it does not give me a desired array back:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (

            [Unit] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 22222
                    [parent_id] => 22222
                    [statistic_date] => 2012-11-14 00:00:00
                )

            [Consultant] => Array
                (
                        [id] => 11111
                        [parent_id] => 22222
                        [statistic_date] => 2011-11-15 00:00:00
                )
      )

    [1] => Array
        (

            [Unit] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 22222
                    [parent_id] => 22222
                    [statistic_date] => 2012-12-14 00:00:00
                )

            [Consultant] => Array
                (
                        [id] => 33333
                        [parent_id] => 22222
                        [statistic_date] => 2011-12-14 00:00:00
                )
      )
)
```

I want it on this form:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (

            [Unit] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 22222
                    [parent_id] => 22222
                    [statistic_date] => 2012-11-14 00:00:00
                )

            [Consultant] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 11111
                            [parent_id] => 22222
                            [statistic_date] => 2011-12-15 00:00:00
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 33333
                            [parent_id] => 22222
                            [statistic_date] => 2011-12-14 00:00:00
                        )
                )
      )
)
```

How do you achieve that? Possible solutions I can think of is by using contain or the Hash:: class, but do not know how.

Any help in the matter will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved the issue. This is what I did. I bind the model on the fly:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

    class Sync extends AppModel {
    function unit() {
        $this->bindModel(array(
            'hasMany' => array(
                'Consultant' => array(
                    'className' => 'Sync',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Consultant.statistic_date BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array('2011-12-01 00:00:00', '2011-12-31 00:00:00')
                    ),
                    'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
                )
            )
        ));

        return $this->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Sync.id = Sync.parent_id'
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

This gives me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (

            [Sync] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 22222
                    [parent_id] => 22222
                    [statistic_date] => 2012-11-14 00:00:00
                )

            [Consultant] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 11111
                            [parent_id] => 22222
                            [statistic_date] => 2011-12-15 00:00:00
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 33333
                            [parent_id] => 22222
                            [statistic_date] => 2011-12-14 00:00:00
                        )
                )
      )
)
```

Comment: Is there any way that we can combine [Sync] and [Consultant] arrays to get one combined array through change in model,not with custom loop

Answer (score 2):

The find has to be done on the Sync model to get the desired effect and I would try contain first. Follow instructions on this page for setting up your models for containable. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

You will then have something like this.

```
$this->Sync->find('all', 
 array(
    'contain'=> 
         array('Consultant'=>
                       array(
                         'conditions' => 
                           array(
                              'Consultant.statistic_date BETWEEN ? AND ?' => 'array(
                                 '2011-12-01 00:00:00', '2011-12-31 00:00:00'
                                 )'
                                )
                            )


              )
      )
);
```

Comment: When trying this out the application is working forever. I mean, minutes and not recieving anything from it. I have about 22.000 rows in syncs table, but don't think that would be the issue.

Is there another way to go around this?

Comment: have you tried setting recursive to -1. The other option would be to do a manual joins http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I reduced the number of rows in syncs and this is what it gives me:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Sync' => array(
        'id' => '11111',
        'parent_id' => '11111',
        'statistic_date' => '2012-12-11 00:00:00'
    ),
    'Unit' => array(
        'id' => '11111',
        'parent_id' => '11111',
        'statistic_date' => '2012-12-11 00:00:00'
    ),
    'Consultant' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '11111',
            'parent_id' => '11111',
            'statistic_date' => '2012-12-11 00:00:00'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '22222',
            'parent_id' => '11111',
            'statistic_date' => '2011-12-14 00:00:00'
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'id' => '33333',
            'parent_id' => '11111',
            'statistic_date' => '2011-12-15 00:00:00'
        )
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'Sync' => array(
        'id' => '22222',
        'parent_id' => '11111',
        'language_code' => null,
        'statistic_date' => '2011-12-14 00:00:00'
    ),
    'Unit' => array(
        'id' => '11111',
        'parent_id' => '11111',
        'statistic_date' => '2012-12-11 00:00:00'
    ),
    'Consultant' => array()
),
(int) 2 => array(
    'Sync' => array(
        'id' => '33333',
        'parent_id' => '11111',
        'statistic_date' => '2011-12-15 00:00:00'
    ),
    'Unit' => array(
        'id' => '11111',
        'parent_id' => '11111',
        'language_code' => null,
        'statistic_date' => '2012-12-11 00:00:00'
    ),
    'Consultant' => array()
)
```

)

Which is closer to what I want to achieve, but not exactly. I don't want the Sync model to show, and I only array[0], not the rest.

Using Hash::extract($data '{n}.Consultant') gives:

```
 array(
(int) 0 => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'id' => '11111',
        'parent_id' => '11111',
        'statistic_date' => '2012-12-11 00:00:00'
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'id' => '22222',
        'parent_id' => '11111',
        'statistic_date' => '2011-12-14 00:00:00'
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'id' => '33333',
        'parent_id' => '11111',
        'statistic_date' => '2011-12-15 00:00:00'
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(),
(int) 2 => array()
```

)

And additionally Hash::filter() on this would give a satistying result, if only the row  where id = parent_id wasn't there.

Hash::filter() gives:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'id' => '11111',
        'parent_id' => '11111',
        'statistic_date' => '2012-12-11 00:00:00'
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'id' => '22222',
        'parent_id' => '11111',
        'statistic_date' => '2011-12-14 00:00:00'
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'id' => '33333',
        'parent_id' => '11111',
        'statistic_date' => '2011-12-15 00:00:00'
    )
)
```

)